# Anyone have Open Bars or similar on a Surly Cross Check or Straggler?

Tags: handlebars, handling

I read around the Internet that many people use a Cross-Check/Straggler as a basis for a relaxed-ish commuter bike. But I'm told by my LBS that running [Open Bars](http://surlybikes.com/parts/handlebars/open_bar) or similar on one of those frames is at best missing the point and at worst will make the bike handle poorly.

Can anyone confirm or deny this from personal experience?

Answer (score 3):

I spent some time on a century ride with a guy who had porteur bars on his cross check.  They certainly did not seem to slow him down or make him uncomfortable.  The Cross Check (full disclosure I do not have one) is the Swiss Army Knife of bikes.  I say go for it... ride it for a season and if it is not your thing re-configure that ultimately configurable rig.

Answer (score 2):

It would bring you back pretty far compared to drop bars.  You may like it but it would change up the geometry quite a bit.

There are some fitness / city bikes that are set up for flat bar.

It is hard to find direct comparison but like in a Niner gravel (drop) versus a hard tail mtn (flat) you see like 565 versus 610 for top tube for the same size person.

Comment: Surly sell a flat-bar Cross Check complete so it's not unheard of, but it seems to be a handlebar with less sweep than their own Open Bars: http://surlybikes.com/bikes/flat_bar_cross_check

Comment: @RobertAtkins Yes they offer a flat bar surly.  Does not mean you would select the same size frame.